# sbt key gets automatically capitalized after migration to sbt 1

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-plugin, sbt1.0

I'm migrating an sbt plugin from 0.13 to 1.0.4
The plugin defines an `InputKey` in the following way:

```
lazy val myKey = InputKey[Unit]("foo-bar", "")
```

To use this key, I would run (from sbt console):

```
foo-bar
```

but after upgrading to sbt 1.0.4, I'm getting the error:

> Not a valid key: foo-bar (similar: fooBar)

What is the reason for this behavior?
And is there a way to make it work with the command `foo-bar` as before?

running `fooBar` works, but the users are already used to `foo-bar` and I would prefer not to change it

Comment: If you find an answer could you please post it as an answer here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that too when I migrated. As you can read [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/sbt-1.0-Release-Notes.html#sbt+1.0.0) in 1.0.0 section:

> Drops sbt 0.12 style hyphen-separated key names (use publishLocal instead of publish-local).

hyphen based task/setting naming was dropped in favor of camel case. AFAIK nothing you can do about it, just roll with it.